# chmod recursive doesn't work

Tags: macos

I'm running on OSX

```
chmod -R 755
```

Isn't the above supposed to change all files in the folder into that permission (755)?

```
usage:  chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
    chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...
```

I get `^` when I use `chmod -R 755`

Some other questions that I have

1. How do you know what permission a file is before you download it? For example, this stack overflow page that I am currently on, what permission is it set as?
2. On github, is there any way I can force permission on a file? For example, I want the index.html file to be downloaded with a 755 permission. Do I need to upload it with a 755 permission?
3. `-rw-r--r--@`  What does the `@` symbol mean in the end?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To change all files in a directory to permissons 755 or rwxr-xr-x you need to specify the files to be changed.

Try:

chmod 755 *

To change all files.   The permissions are bitfileds equaling 421 for rwx, for read write execute, respectively, listed as owner, group, other/everybody.   Add together the bits you'd like for the permissions, so 4+2+1 is 7 for rwx for owner, 4+1=5 is r-x for group members, and 4+1=5 for everybody else.  This results in rwx(owner)r-x(group)r-x(others)

When uploading, it depends on the method used, an ftp server will change permissions to suit the configuration.